# Doing a Requery on a Form opened with acFormAdd creates a new record

Tags: ms-access, vba

Lets asume a user wants to create a new record and to do so he opens a form. When opening a form with

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", acNormal, "", "", acFormAdd, acDialog
```

Access will open the form with the *data pointer* set on a new/empty record. The user can now fill the form **but** some user actions may require a `Me.Requery` in order to take place. If you do so, the form "looses" the data pointer on the currently created and modified record and jumps to a new, empty record. Even a `Me.Dirty = False` before the requery wont prevent Access from doing so. Im pretty sure this behavior results from the paramter `acFormAdd`.

In contrast, opening a form with

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", acNormal, "", "WHERE-CLAUSE", acFormEdit, acDialog
```

resolves the behavior but will only work for existing records.

You can imagine that this unrequested behavior is not what I'm expecting because it forces me to implement an ugly workaround with closing and reopening the from when certain conditions are fulfilled.

So, I'm wondering if there is a much easier way that helps me avoid the behevior described above. I would very much appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Well, 2021 and I have the same problem and can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

See whether requerying selected form controls can accomplish what you need without requerying the entire form.

For example to requery a combo box named *cboUserID*, you can do this ...

```vb
Me.cboUserID.Requery
```

Comment: I need those requeries because I change the database "manually" with SQL queries. When I do so I need to requery the form because otherwise Access sometimes tells me that the data has been changed by another user and needs to be refreshed (I dont know the exact error code).

So I'm wondering if your approach makes sure that I won't run into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution might be to use .recalc instead.

```
DoCmd.Save
Me.recalc
```